# How to create different menu's for not logged in visitors and for logged in members?

Tags: php, customization, menus

I'm creating a website which will provide services to members and I want to make it so that when a not logged in person comes to the website the menu is specifically designed for sales pages to make him register, but when a logged in person comes in he sees a different menu that is for the sole purpose of delivering the services. I want to make this because I don't want my already members always going to the website to read the sales pages. I would so appreciate your help, just can't figure this out on my own. And I think this would be pretty neat also :) hoping for an answer

Comment: "use is_user_logged_in conditional tag and apply a different menu accordingly" Cool, but where do I put this?

Comment: Search your themes templates until you find your menu. Then alter this with the code mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 4):

You can do that by using 2 different menus ([wp_nav_menu](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu)).

use [is_user_logged_in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) conditional tag and apply a different menu accordingly:

```
if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'logged_user' ));
} else {
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'new_user' ));
}
```

**Edit**
This code goes where you'd usually put your regular menu in the theme - probably header.php

Also, make sure that you add the menus to the actual theme, i.e. in function.php add the folowing lines of code:

```
if (function_exists('register_nav_menu')):
    register_nav_menu('logged_user', 'Existing users menu');
    register_nav_menu('new_user', 'New users menu');
endif;
```

Comment: Dammit, just beat me to that exact same answer. Upvoted.

Comment: But where do I put this code in?

Comment: @hannit_cohen where would I put this code in? I have a child theme, if that helps.

Comment: Added the required code upside

Comment: "*But where do I put this code in?*" only you can answer that question, as it is entirely dependent upon your Theme. See the `wp_nav_menu()` Codex entry that @hannitcohen linked in his answer.