# Show different menus for login / logout user

Tags: menus, user-access

I am try to show different menus for login and logout user. [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44371/how-to-create-different-menus-for-not-logged-in-visitors-and-for-logged-in-memb) is perfect solution to do this and also work on Twenty eleven theme. But when I try to add this code to my woo theme's defination (in header.php) I got this error `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in C:\xampp-portable\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\definition\header.php on line 63` How to fix it?

This is code of Definition's header.php:

```
<?php
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;
/**
 * Header Template
 *
 * Here we setup all logic and XHTML that is required for the header section of all screens.
 *
 * @package WooFramework
 * @subpackage Template
 */

 global $woo_options, $woocommerce;

?><!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>" />
<title><?php woo_title( '' ); ?></title>
<?php woo_meta(); ?>
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php echo esc_url( get_bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ) ); ?>" />
<?php
wp_head();
woo_head();
?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<?php woo_top(); ?>

<div id="wrapper">

    <?php woo_header_before(); ?>

    <header id="header">
        <div class="col-full">

            <?php woo_header_inside(); ?>

            <hgroup>
                <span class="nav-toggle"><a href="#navigation"><span><?php _e( 'Navigation', 'woothemes' ); ?></span></a></span>
                <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                <h2 class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></h2>
            </hgroup>

            <?php woo_nav_before(); ?>

            <nav id="navigation" class="col-full" role="navigation">

                <?php /*
                if ( function_exists( 'has_nav_menu' ) && has_nav_menu( 'primary-menu' ) ) {
                    wp_nav_menu( array( 'depth' => 6, 'sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'container' => 'ul', 'menu_id' => 'main-nav', 'menu_class' => 'nav fl', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu' ) );
                } else { */
                if (is_user_logged_in()) {
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'logged_user' ));
} else {
      wp_nav_menu(array('theme_location' => 'new_user' ));
}
                ?>
                <ul id="main-nav" class="nav fl">
                    <?php if ( is_page() ) $highlight = 'page_item'; else $highlight = 'page_item current_page_item'; ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo $highlight; ?>"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Home', 'woothemes' ); ?></a></li>
                    <?php wp_list_pages( 'sort_column=menu_order&depth=6&title_li=&exclude=' ); ?>
                </ul><!-- /#nav -->
                <?php } ?>
                <?php if ( is_woocommerce_activated() && isset( $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] ) && 'true' == $woo_options['woocommerce_header_cart_link'] ) { ?>
                    <ul class="nav cart fr">
                        <li><a class="cart-contents" href="<?php echo esc_url( $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url() ); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'View your shopping cart', 'woothemes' ); ?>"><?php echo sprintf( _n('%d item', '%d items', $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count, 'woothemes' ), $woocommerce->cart->cart_contents_count );?> - <?php echo $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total(); ?></a></li>
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>

            </nav><!-- /#navigation -->

            <?php woo_nav_after(); ?>

        </div><!-- /.col-full -->
    </header><!-- /#header -->

    <?php woo_content_before(); ?>
```

Comment: Moderator, please fix code view

Comment: At your service. :) Please read our [fantastic editing help](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed your code in a line number editor to find line `63`. I have marked the line with the extra `}` (well it's in line `64` in my editor)

[image]

This is a `PHP` error you got. Try to remove this line.